# Can't apply radius to submit button

Tags: css

I am trying to make the borders of my submit button round but it doesn't seem to work when I try this:

```
input[type="submit"].button2,
button[type="submit"].button2{
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  border-color: #d21151;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #d21151;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: Inspect that element and see if other css style is overriding your selector

Comment: Please post you HTML. You could build a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You defined `border-radius` twice. Delete the `border-radius: 5px;` that you set a little lower.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the 5px border radius line and it still doesn't work. HTML:


<button type="submit" class="button2">Submit</button>

Comment: There is another border radius set to 0 with !important but I don't know what to do about that?

Comment: @Jonathan Can you remove the `!mportant` from there?

Comment: @Jonathan if you have !important then it will have the most priority. remove it.. And remember you should never use !important

Comment: I am using an existing theme that has it built in. If I remove it won't it break other stuff?

Comment: @Jonathan unlucky.... yes it might break.. Then only thing is make your style important too.. Also place your css file after the theme css file.. Concept is since both have important in them, the file which is placed last in the HTML DOM reading from top will have the priority.

Comment: @Jonathan, can you add **:not(.button2)** to that selector something like `.bad .selector button[type="submit"]:not(.button2) { border-radius: 0!important; .... }`

Comment: Reddy, your comment about making my style important too has worked for me and the simplest solution. I don't know how to accept that as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your styles are working fine. Here is a demo snippet.

```css
input[type="submit"].button2,
button[type="submit"].button2{

  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  border-color: #d21151;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #d21151; 
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="button2" />

<button type="submit" class="button2" >submit</button>
```

Inspect the element and see if any other external CSS rule is applying on it. This can happen if the priority of the other rules are higher than yours.

---

You have lots of information available over the internet related to CSS priorities, Give yourself some time to have a hold on this topic. Here are few useful links   **[Priority Calculation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector)** , **[Priority Rules](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/wearable/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm)**